# I have a 120/240 dryer from Canada, and want to use it in a 240v country.

Tags: dryer, 120-240v

The dryer electric driagram identifies  a RED L1 wire, a WHITE LN one, and other Black as L2.
The suplpy cord has a RED, WHITE and BLACK wires and the green ground as well.
How should I connect the wires to have the 240 V from the wall outlet and the 120V trough a 240 to 120 transfo?

Comment: Wire it by the same colors as you  said you have. Red to red, black  to black  white to white, and green to a ground terminal or a ground screw.  In the breaker panel, red and black are hot white is neutral and the green is the ground.If that is too hard or you don't feel safe,  call an electrician to do the hook-up.

Comment: Thanks  alotGeorge, my doubt is that since originally the 240 V is supossed to be obtained from the red and black wires, each 120 V but different phase, now that I have the 240 V directly from the wall outlet, should I connect  the white and black to the wall to get 240?

Comment: So far, connecting the red and white to 120V, I have everything going but the heathers, that use 240V and in the digrama are supplied through the black wire.

Comment: I would wait for 1 of the master electricians that monitor this site to give you instructions on the correct way to utilize this power and exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: What's the make and model of your dryer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very often, these types of dryers are also marketed in Pacific Rim markets where only 240V is available.  In this case, they build the dryer slightly differently, adding an internal 240V/120V transformer for the small number of 120V loads inside the machine (typically the motor).

I would start by getting the schematic for the 240V version of this dryer. Then compare it to the 120V schematic, and see what needs to change.

DO NOT - DO NOT - use a "step down" transformer without extreme care for how neutrals are bonded in the dryer and with your power supply.  If a step-down transformer isn't applied painstakingly correctly, it would end up energizing the chassis of your dryer at 230V.

Answer (score 0):

This likely won't work.  Typically the motor and controls in a north American the dryer are designed for 120 volts.  Only the heating element is a north American dryer is powered with the 240 volts. .  North American power is delivered to your home in what is called split phase.  There are two hots and a neutral. If you connect a load across the two hots, you get 240 volts. If you connect between one hot and the neutral you get 120.  So in your dryers case, the heating element is connected across the two hot leads and the motor and controls are connected between one hot and the neutral.  In the European system you have single phase. The hot is 240 and the other is the neutral.  There's is no way to get the 120 off this system. To run the motor and controls.

Comment: Thanks Jim, so far connecting the neutral and red, to a transfo I run the motor and controls normally.

Comment: So what´s left is the heating element , my doubt is if connecting the black  wire (which accordingly with the diagram feeds the heating elements) and the neutral to 240, will work without impoacting on the 120 circuit (neutral and red wire)